# Unable to Install scipy.ndimage

Tags: python, scipy

Because VSC says `unresolved import 'scipy.ndimage'` for `from scipy.ndimage import interpolation as inter`  So I found the [binary package for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs) at the bottom of https://scipy.org/install.html. I was able to

1. successfully install the required Windows VC++ buildtool, reboot
2. download the ndimage-1.3.1.tar.gz from above
3. `python setup.py install` gave me following error

```
building 'ndimage._lib._ccallback_c' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Indimage/src -Indimage/_lib "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcndimage/_lib/_ccallback_c.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\ndimage/_lib/_ccallback_c.obj
_ccallback_c.c
c1: **fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'ndimage/_lib/_ccallback_c.c': No such file or directory**
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Running Python v 3.7.4

Here is the downloadables, no 64-bit for Intel. `python -m pip install --user ndimage-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-win32.whl` gave me `ERROR: ndimage-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`
[image]

Comment: Your version is `python 3.7`??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh `python --version` says 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention your `python version 3.7` so you can check is it `64 bit` or `32 bit` by

```
(py37_64) E:\>python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

so from my environment is mention as 64 bit with `python 3.7`

Now for your platform `python 3.7` so it should be `ndimage‑1.3.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` or `ndimage‑1.3.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`

Why you are installing wheel file which contains for `python 3.9` so that's why it giving platform not supported

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps and info, works out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That site is for windows *binaries*, as in the pre-built wheel files (`.whl`). Find the matching `.whl` file for your python version and 32/64 bit (e.g `scipy‑1.6.3‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl` for scipy 1.6.3 for 64-bit Python 3.9). Then install it via `pip install some_wheel_file.whl`. This avoids needing to compile with a .tar.gz source distribution.

Edit: amd64 is for all 64-bit CPUs, not just AMD CPUs.

Comment: Please see updated post above. Also tried `pip install some.whl`.

Comment: @Jeb50 amd64 is for 64-bit, regardless if its amd or intel (its a misnomer unfortunately)

Comment: ran `amd64` got platform incompatible msg.

Comment: Appreciate everything.